# jQuery based menu breaks when moved to a different site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've used a jQuery Mega Menu that i found at jQueryScript.net and it works great on my testing server, and was working fine when i moved it over to the site it is going to go on eventually, but for whatever reason it now has broken on the actual site after I've made no changes to anything related to it. I've spent several hours trying to find the solution and was hoping someone might have come across a similar issue in the past.

Here is the testing link I have up where it works fine: http://sandbox.corybolles.com/ms_mega_menu/

And here is the actual site: https://www.millenniumseating.com/?sessionthemeid=28

As a side note, this is my first time using SO, so if I'm using this entirely wrong please do let me know, I'm not trying to get anyone to do my work for me, I'm just looking for a different perspective on something that I might have overlooked.

UPDATE: Here is the related
JS

```
(function() {
    (jQuery)('#header-wrapper ul.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('> a').addClass('expanded-menu');
    }, function() {
        $(this).parent().find('> a').removeClass('expanded-menu');
    });
    (jQuery).fn.megamenu = function(width) {
        var $that = (jQuery)(this),
            $window = (jQuery)(window);

        function update() {
            $that.find('.megamenu').each(function() {
                var $this = (jQuery)(this),
                    windowW = $window.width(),
                    offSetLeft = $this.offset().left,
                    parentWidth = $this.width(),
                    megaMenuCols = $this.find('> .dropdown > li.has-dropdown').length,
                    megaMenuWidth, mainMenuWidth = $('#top .top-bar').width(),
                    dropdownWidth = 295,
                    longestMenu = 1;
                $this.find('> .dropdown > li.has-dropdown > .dropdown').each(function() {
                    var currentLength = (jQuery)(this).find('> li').length;
                    if (currentLength > longestMenu) {
                        longestMenu = currentLength;
                    }
                });
                $this.find('> .dropdown > li.has-dropdown > .dropdown').each(function() {
                    var $dropdown = (jQuery)(this);
                    var currentLength = $dropdown.find('> li').length;
                    if (currentLength < longestMenu) {
                        for (var i = 1; i <= longestMenu - currentLength; i++) {
                            $dropdown.append('<li class="empty-megamenu"></li>');
                        }
                    }
                });
                dropdownWidth = mainMenuWidth / megaMenuCols;
                var megaMenuWidth = megaMenuCols * dropdownWidth > width ? width : mainMenuWidth,
                    blankGutterW = windowW * 0.9 < width ? windowW * 0.05 : (windowW - width) / 2;
                var megaMenuRight = megaMenuWidth / 2 - parentWidth / 2;
                megaMenuRight = (megaMenuWidth / 2 > offSetLeft + parentWidth / 2 - blankGutterW) ? width - (offSetLeft + parentWidth) : megaMenuRight;
                var megaMenuPosition = windowW - offSetLeft - parentWidth - blankGutterW
                if (windowW > 1300 || megaMenuRight > megaMenuPosition) {
                    megaMenuRight = megaMenuPosition;
                }
                $this.find('> .dropdown > li.has-dropdown').css('width', dropdownWidth + 'px');
                $this.find('> .dropdown > li.has-dropdown > .dropdown').css({
                    'width': dropdownWidth + 'px',
                    'min-width': dropdownWidth + 'px'
                });
                $this.find('> .dropdown').css({
                    'width': megaMenuWidth + 'px',
                    'right': -megaMenuRight + 'px'
                });
            });
            $that.find('li:not(.megamenu).has-dropdown > .dropdown').each(function() {
                var $this = (jQuery)(this);
                var windowW = (jQuery)(window).width(),
                    offSetLeft = $this.offset().left;
                if ($this.width() + offSetLeft > windowW) {
                    $this.css({
                        'left': '-100%',
                        'max-width': '100%'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        $(window).resize(update);
        update();
    };
    (function hoverdelay() {
        (jQuery)('#top .top-bar:not(.expanded) .top-bar-section li.has-dropdown').each(function() {
            var $this = (jQuery)(this),
                menuTimeoutShow, menuTimeoutHide;
            $this.on("mouseenter tap", function(e) {
                if (e.type == "tap") e.stopPropagation();
                clearTimeout(menuTimeoutShow);
                clearTimeout(menuTimeoutHide);
                menuTimeoutShow = setTimeout(function() {
                    $this.addClass("hippo-menu-hovered");
                    if ($this.hasClass("hippo-menu-hovered")) {
                        $this.children('ul').stop().css("visibility", "visible").animate({
                            "opacity": 1
                        }, 200);
                    }
                }, 300);
            });
            $this.on("mouseleave", function(e) {
                clearTimeout(menuTimeoutShow);
                clearTimeout(menuTimeoutHide);
                menuTimeoutHide = setTimeout(function() {
                    $this.removeClass("hippo-menu-hovered");
                    if (!$this.hasClass("hippo-menu-hovered")) {
                        $this.children("ul").css({
                            "opacity": 0,
                            "visibility": "hidden"
                        });
                    }
                }, 300);
            });
        });
    })();
})(jQuery);
(jQuery)('.top-bar-section').megamenu(1200);
```

and CSS

```
.right {
    float: right!important;
}#
header - wrapper {
    position: absolute;background: #333;color:# fff;width: 100 % ;margin: 0 auto; - webkit - box - shadow: 0 0 3 px 1 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); - moz - box - shadow: 0 0 3 px 1 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);box - shadow: 0 0 3 px 1 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);z - index: 10000;
}.top - bar {
    position: relative;height: 60 px;line - height: 60 px;background - color: transparent;overflow: hidden; - webkit - transition: height 0.4 s ease - out; - moz - transition: height 0.4 s ease - out; - o - transition: height 0.4 s ease - out;transition: height 0.4 s ease - out;
}.top - bar - section li.megamenu {
    width: 100 % ;
}.top - bar - section li.megamenu > .dropdown {
    min - width: 100 % ;
    right: auto;
    left: 100 % ;
}.top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu > .dropdown > li.has - dropdown, .top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu > .dropdown > li.has - dropdown > .dropdown {
    width: 210 px;
}.top - bar ul {
    margin - bottom: 0;
    list - style: none;
}.top - bar.row {
    max - width: none;
}.top - bar form, .top - bar input {
    margin - bottom: 0 px;
}.top - bar input {
    height: 2.45e m;
}.top - bar.button {
    padding - top: .5e m;
    padding - bottom: .5e m;
    margin - bottom: 0;
}.top - bar.title - area {
    position: relative;margin: 0;
}.top - bar.name, .top - bar.name a {
    line - height: 60 px;
    height: 60 px;
}.top - bar.name a {
    font - size: 20 px;
    font - weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    width: 50 % ; - webkit - transition: none; - moz - transition: none; - o - transition: none;
    transition: none;
}.top - bar.toggle - topbar a, .top - bar.expanded.toggle - topbar a {
    display: none;color: #f4f4f4; - webkit - transition: none; - moz - transition: none; - o - transition: none;transition: none;
}.top - bar.expanded.toggle - topbar a span {
    -webkit - box - shadow: 0 10 px 0 1 px #888888,0 16px 0 1px # 888888, 0 22 px 0 1 px #888888;-moz-box-shadow:0 10px 0 1px # 888888, 0 16 px 0 1 px #888888,0 22px 0 1px # 888888;
    box - shadow: 0 10 px 0 1 px #888888,0 16px 0 1px # 888888, 0 22 px 0 1 px #888888;}.top-bar-section{position:relative;left:0;width:auto;-webkit-transition:left 0.35s cubic-bezier(.58,.25,.2,.93);-moz-transition:left 0.35s cubic-bezier(.58,.25,.2,.93);-o-transition:left 0.35s cubic-bezier(.58,.25,.2,.93);transition:left 0.35s cubic-bezier(.58,.25,.2,.93);}.top-bar-section ul{width:100%;height:auto;display:block;margin:0;}.top-bar-section .divider,.top-bar-section [role= "separator"] {
    border - bottom: solid 1 px# f4f4f4;
    border - top: solid 1 px# f4f4f4;
    clear: both;
    height: 1 px;
    width: 100 % ;
}.top - bar - section ul li > a {
    display: block;width: 100 % ;color: #fff;padding: 12 px 0;font - size: 1e m; - webkit - transition: none; - moz - transition: none; - o - transition: none;transition: 　none;
}.top - bar - section ul li.active > a {
    background: #fff;color: #949494;}.top-bar-section .has-form{padding:15px;}.top-bar-section ul.dropdown li:not(.has-dropdown)>a:hover,.top-bar.expanded ul li:not(.has-dropdown)>a:hover{color:# eaeaea;background - color: #656565;}.top-bar-section .dropdown{position:absolute;left:100%;top:60px;visibility:hidden;opacity:0;}.top-bar-section .dropdown li{width:100%;height:auto;}.top-bar-section .dropdown li a{white-space:nowrap;font-weight:normal;-webkit-transition:none;-moz-transition:none;-o-transition:none;transition:none;}.top-bar-section .dropdown label{padding:8px 15px 2px;margin-bottom:0;text-transform:uppercase;color:# fff;font - weight: bold;font - size: 0.625e m;
}.top - bar - js - breakpoint {
    width: 900 px!important;visibility: hidden;
}.js - generated {
    display: block;
}.mini - search {
    display: none;
}
body.mobile.parallax - section, .off - canvas - wrap.move - left.parallax - section {
    background - attachment: scroll!important;
    background - position: 50 % 0!important;
}.mobile - slide - menu {
    display: block;
}
a.exit - off - canvas.mobile - menu - off {
    background - color: #333333!important;position:relative!important;width:260px!important;height:40px!important;line-height:40px;padding-left:30%;}a.exit-off-canvas.mobile-menu-off i{vertical-align:-1px;}a.exit-off-canvas.mobile-menu-off span{color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);}.left-off-canvas-menu,.right-off-canvas-menu{width:260px;top:0;bottom:0;height:100%;position:absolute;overflow-y:auto;background:# 333333;
    z - index: 1001;
    box - sizing: content - box;
}.right - off - canvas - menu.dropdown li.has - dropdown {
    position: relative;
}.right - off - canvas - menu.dropdown li.has - dropdown.off - canvas - dropdown {
    position: absolute;left: 74 % ;top: 0;width: 50 px;height: 42 px;text - align: right;padding - top: 13 px;padding - right: 11 px;color: #fff;cursor: pointer;
}.right - off - canvas - menu.dropdown li.has - dropdown.off - canvas - dropdown: hover {
    color: #222;}.right-off-canvas-menu .dropdown .dropdown{display:none;}section.left-small,section.right-small{width:2.8125rem;height:2.8125rem;position:absolute;top:0;}nav.tab-bar{background:transparent;color:# fff;height: 30 px;line - height: 2.8125 rem;position: relative;position: absolute;top: 35 px;width: 30 px;right: 5 % ;z - index: 20000;
}
nav.tab - bar a i {
    font - size: 30 px;
    vertical - align: middle;
    color: #656565!important;}nav.tab-bar h1,nav.tab-bar h2,nav.tab-bar h3,nav.tab-bar h4,nav.tab-bar h5,nav.tab-bar h6{color:white;font-weight:bold;line-height:2.8125rem;margin:0;}nav.tab-bar h1,nav.tab-bar h2,nav.tab-bar h3,nav.tab-bar h4{font-size:1.125rem;}section.left-small{border-right:solid 1px # 1 a1a1a;
    box - shadow: 1 px 0 0 #4d4d4d;left:0;}section.right-small{border-left:solid 1px # 4 d4d4d;
    box - shadow: -1 px 0 0 #1a1a1a;right:0;}section.tab-bar-section{padding:0 0.625rem;position:absolute;text-align:center;height:2.8125rem;top:0;}section.tab-bar-section.left{left:0;right:2.8125rem;}section.tab-bar-section.right{left:2.8125rem;right:0;}section.tab-bar-section.middle{left:2.8125rem;right:2.8125rem;}a.menu-icon{width:30px;height:30px;display:block;line-height:30px;padding:0;color:white;position:relative;}a.menu-icon span{position:absolute;display:block;width:1rem;height:0;left:0.8125rem;top:0.3125rem;-webkit-box-shadow:0 10px 0 1px white,0 16px 0 1px white,0 22px 0 1px white;box-shadow:0 10px 0 1px white,0 16px 0 1px white,0 22px 0 1px white;}a.menu-icon:hover span{-webkit-box-shadow:0 10px 0 1px # b3b3b3, 0 16 px 0 1 px# b3b3b3, 0 22 px 0 1 px# b3b3b3;
    box - shadow: 0 10 px 0 1 px# b3b3b3, 0 16 px 0 1 px# b3b3b3, 0 22 px 0 1 px# b3b3b3;
}.left - off - canvas - menu {
    -webkit - transform: translate3d(-100 % , 0, 0); - moz - transform: translate3d(-100 % , 0, 0); - ms - transform: translate3d(-100 % , 0, 0); - o - transform: translate3d(-100 % , 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100 % , 0, 0);
}.right - off - canvas - menu {
    -webkit - transform: translate3d(100 % , 0, 0); - moz - transform: translate3d(100 % , 0, 0); - ms - transform: translate3d(100 % , 0, 0); - o - transform: translate3d(100 % , 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100 % , 0, 0);
    right: 0;
}
ul.off - canvas - list {
    list - style - type: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 3 px;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.off - canvas - list li label {
    padding: 0.3 rem 0.9375 rem;color: #999999;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:bold;background:# 444444;border - top: 1 px solid #5e5e5e;border-bottom:none;margin:0;}ul.off-canvas-list li a{display:block;padding:0.66667rem;color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);border-bottom:1px solid # 3 D3D3D;
}.move - right > .inner - wrap {
    -webkit - transform: translate3d(260 px, 0, 0); - moz - transform: translate3d(260 px, 0, 0); - ms - transform: translate3d(260 px, 0, 0); - o - transform: translate3d(260 px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(260 px, 0, 0);
}.move - right a.exit - off - canvas {
    transition: background 300 ms ease;cursor: pointer;box - shadow: -4 px 0 4 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
    4 px 0 4 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);display: block;position: absolute;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;width: 100 % ;height: 100 % ;z - index: 50000;
}.move - left > .inner - wrap {
    -webkit - transform: translate3d(-260 px, 0, 0); - moz - transform: translate3d(-260 px, 0, 0); - ms - transform: translate3d(-260 px, 0, 0); - o - transform: translate3d(-260 px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-260 px, 0, 0);
}.move - left a.exit - off - canvas {
    transition: background 500 ms ease;cursor: pointer;box - shadow: -4 px 0 4 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
    4 px 0 4 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);display: block;position: absolute;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;width: 100 % ;height: 100 % ;z - index: 50000;
}.ie9.left - off - canvas - menu {
    left: -260 px;
}.ie9.right - off - canvas - menu {
    right: -260 px;
}.ie9.move - left > .inner - wrap {
    right: 260 px;
}.ie9.move - right > .inner - wrap {
    left: 260 px;
}
@media only screen and(min - width: 900 px) {#
    top,
    .top - bar {
        -webkit - transition: height 0.2 s linear!important; - moz - transition: height 0.2 s linear!important; - o - transition: height 0.2 s linear!important;
        transition: height 0.2 s linear!important;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > li > a,
    .top - bar.name a,
    .mini - search.searchform {
        -webkit - transition: line - height 0.18 s linear, color 0.5 s ease!important; - moz - transition: line - height 0.18 s linear, color 0.5 s ease!important; - o - transition: line - height 0.18 s linear, color 0.5 s ease!important;
        transition: line - height 0.18 s linear, color 0.5 s ease!important;
    }.top - bar - section ul li {
        position: relative;list - style: none;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > li li.has - dropdown: hover > .dropdown {
        opacity: 1;
    }.top - bar - section li.hippo - menu - hovered: hover > .dropdown,
    .top - bar - section li.hippo - menu - hovered > .dropdown,
    .top - bar - section li.hippo - menu - hovered.megamenu.dropdown,
    .top - bar - section li.hippo - menu - hovered.megamenu: hover.dropdown {
        visibility: visible!important;opacity: 1!important;
    }.top - bar: not(.expanded).top - bar - section > ul > li > a {
        border - bottom: none!important;
        display: inline - block;
        line - height: 60 px;
    }.top - bar: not(.expanded).top - bar - section > ul > li > a: before {
        opacity: 0;
    }.top - bar: not(.expanded).top - bar - section > ul > li > a.expanded - menu: before {
        opacity: 0.7;width: 6 px;height: 6 px;margin - left: -3 px; - webkit - animation: breathing 2.5 s infinite linear; - moz - animation: breathing 2.5 s infinite linear; - o - animation: breathing 2.5 s infinite linear;animation: breathing 2.5 s infinite linear;
    }.top - bar: not(.expanded).top - bar - section > ul > li > a: hover: before {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }#
    top {
        height: 60 px;background: #fff;width: 100 % ;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > li[class *= "current"] > a,
    .small - nav ul li[class *= "current"] > a {
        color: #949494;}.top-bar{*zoom:1;overflow:visible;}.top-bar:before,.top-bar:after{content:" ";display:table;}.top-bar:after{clear:both;}.top-bar .toggle-topbar{display:none;}.top-bar .title-area{float:left;}.top-bar .name a{width:auto;}.top-bar input,.top-bar .button{line-height:2em;font-size:0.9em;height:2em;padding:0 10px;position:relative;top:0;}.top-bar.expanded{background:# fff;
    }.contain - to - grid.top - bar {
        max - width: 75e m;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin - bottom: 1.875e m;
    }.top - bar - section {
        margin - top: 0; - webkit - transition: none; - moz - transition: none; - o - transition: none;
        transition: none;
        left: 0!important;
    }.top - bar - section ul {
        width: auto;height: auto!important;display: inline;
    }.top - bar - section ul li {
        float: left;
    }.top - bar - section ul li.js - generated {
        display: none;
    }.top - bar - section li a: not(.button) {
        line - height: 100 px;
        padding: 0 15 px;
    }.top - bar - section li a: not(.button).hover {
        background: white;
    }.top - bar - section.has - dropdown > a {
        padding - right: 15 px!important; - webkit - transition: none; - moz - transition: none; - o - transition: none;
        transition: none;
    }.top - bar - section.has - dropdown > a: after {
        content: ""!important;
    }.top - bar - section.has - dropdown.moved {
        position: relative;
    }.top - bar - section.has - dropdown.moved > .dropdown {
        visibility: hidden;
    }.top - bar - section.has - dropdown.hover > .dropdown,
    .top - bar - section.has - dropdown.not - click: hover > .dropdown {
        visibility: visible;
    }.top - bar - section.has - dropdown.dropdown li.has - dropdown > a: after {
        border: none;content: "";margin - top: -16 px;right: 5 px;
    }.top - bar - section li.dropdown {
        left: 0;background: transparent;min - width: 210 px;
    }.top - bar - section.dropdown li a {
        color: #222;line-height:2.3;padding:7px 15px;-webkit-transition:background-color 0.5s ease,color 0.5s ease;-moz-transition:background-color 0.5s ease,color 0.5s ease;-o-transition:background-color 0.5s ease,color 0.5s ease;transition:background-color 0.5s ease,color 0.5s ease;}.top-bar-section .dropdown li{background-color:# ddd;
    }.top - bar - section.dropdown li label {
        white - space: nowrap;
        background: #1e1e1e;}.top-bar-section li.empty-megamenu{height:37px;background-color:# ddd;
    }.top - bar - section li: not(.megamenu).dropdown li.dropdown {
        left: 100 % ;top: 0;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > .divider,
    .top - bar - section > ul > [role = "separator"] {
        border - bottom: none;
        border - top: none;
        border - right: solid 1 px# fff;
        border - left: solid 1 px# fff;
        clear: none;
        height: 45 px;
        width: 0 px;
    }.top - bar - section.has - form {
        background: #111111;padding:0 15px;height:45px;}.top-bar-section ul.right li:not(.megamenu) .dropdown{right:auto;left:0;}.top-bar-section ul.right li .dropdown li .dropdown{left:100%;}.top-bar-section li.megamenu{width:auto!important;}.top-bar-section li.megamenu>.dropdown{left:auto!important;}.top-bar-section>ul>li.megamenu>.dropdown>li.has-dropdown>a{position:relative;display:inline-block;top:0;margin:0;max-width:150px;}.top-bar-section>ul>li.megamenu>.dropdown{position:absolute;}.top-bar-section>ul>li.megamenu>.dropdown>li.has-dropdown:first-child>.dropdown>li:last-child{border-bottom-left-radius:3px;}.top-bar-section>ul>li.megamenu>.dropdown>li.has-dropdown:last-child>.dropdown>li:last-child{border-bottom-right-radius:3px;}.top-bar-section>ul>li.megamenu>.dropdown>li>.dropdown>li a{padding-top:4px!important;padding-bottom:4px!important;height:37px;}.top-bar-section>ul>li.megamenu .dropdown a{padding-left:17px;}.top-bar-section>ul>li.megamenu>.dropdown>li{padding-top:3px!important;}.top-bar-section>ul>li.megamenu>.dropdown>li>a{font-weight:bold;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px;font-size:12px;padding-bottom:25px!important;}.top-bar-section>ul>li.megamenu>.dropdown>li>.dropdown>li:last-child{height:50px!important;}.top-bar-section>ul>li.megamenu:hover>.dropdown>li.has-dropdown{visibility:visible;opacity:1;}.top-bar-section>ul>li.megamenu>.dropdown>li.has-dropdown>a{max-width:100%!important;display:inline-block;float:left;margin:0!important;color:# 222;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu > .dropdown > li.has - dropdown > .dropdown {
        left: 0!important;top: 45 px;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu: hover > .dropdown > li.has - dropdown > .dropdown {
        visibility: visible;opacity: 1;
    }.no - js.top - bar - section ul li: hover > a {
        background: #090909;color:white;}.no-js .top-bar-section ul li:active>a{background:# 090909;color: white;
    }.no - js.top - bar - section.has - dropdown: hover > .dropdown {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
@media only screen and(min - width: 1200 px) {.top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu > .dropdown > li.has - dropdown, .top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu > .dropdown > li.has - dropdown > .dropdown {
        width: 295 px;
    }.top - bar - section li.empty - megamenu {
        height: 41 px;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu > .dropdown > li > .dropdown > li: not(: last - child): not(: first - child) a {
        padding - top: 6 px!important;
        padding - bottom: 6 px!important;
        height: 41 px;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu.dropdown a {
        padding - left: 30 px!important;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu > .dropdown > li {
        padding - top: 10 px!important;
        padding - bottom: 5 px!important;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu > .dropdown > li > a {
        padding - bottom: 10 px!important;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu > .dropdown > li > .dropdown > li: last - child {
        height: 55 px!important;
    }.top - bar - section > ul > li.megamenu > .dropdown > li.has - dropdown > .dropdown {
        top: 55 px!important;
    }
}
@media only screen and(min - width: 1300 px) {.inner - wrap > .box - layout {
        max - width: 1200 px!important;
    }.box - layout# header - wrapper, .box - layout.small - nav {
        max - width: 1200 px!important;
    }
}
a.hoverNone: hover {
        background: none!important;color: #222!important;}
```

Again, these are not my bits of code, they came from an online "plugin" at jQueryScript.net

Comment: Could you please explain what's not working?? Styles? cos menu opens as expected when compared with your working site..

Comment: Sorry, here is the issue I am having. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ar16Y5FSBtX0JXdWlBRGJjSTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: **[Looks great for me though](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2dluc89&s=9#.WNvCcDvfrIU)**

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure. I've tested it on multiple browsers and devices and this is what i get on all of them (Have tried different networks as well)